# Dual Exchange account email client

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to find a Ubuntu mail client that can have multiple exchange mailboxes on the same session similar to what outlook does

Example

Inbox1 is my primary account but I have access and send as permissions to inbox2

I have both accounts set up on my profile in outlook, and am looking for something that will do the same in Ubuntu.

Anyone know the application I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Thunderbird.  It has these features:

> - Supports multiple POP and IMAP accounts for all your email addresses
> - Easy account setup with the account wizard
> - Powerful, yet simple-to-use search and filtering
> - Saved searches
> - Multiple viewing options, including vertical columns
> - Message threading and conversation views
> - One-click address book adding
> - Attachment reminders
> - Tabbed message viewing
> - Message archiving, perfect for Gmail users
> - Built-in junk filtering
> - A migration assistant that helps you move your accounts from other    email clients like Outlook
> - An open source add-on infrastructure that lets you customize    Thunderbird for your needs
> - Integration with the GNOME desktop on many distributions, including    Ubuntu <sup>1</sup>

You can use Thunderbird as client for Microsoft Exchange 2010 server on Ubuntu.  To be able to connect to Microsoft Exchange 2010 server from Thunderbird you may have to install an Exchange gateway called DavMail.  For more info on DavMail, installation instructions, and to download it [Visit DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5871840/the-best-email-client-for-linux)</sup>